# Getting an empty array while submitting form in redux-form with material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, redux-form

I am using `redux-form` with `material-ui` as discussed [here](http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-rc.1/examples/material-ui/)

My code is a follows

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';  
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField'
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap'

const renderTextField = props => (
  <TextField hintText={props.label}
    floatingLabelText={props.label}
    errorText={props.touched && props.error}
    {...props}
  />
)

let LoginForm = (props) => {

    return (
            <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
                <div>
                    <Field name="loginEmail" component={renderTextField} type="email" label="Email Address"/>
                </div>              
                <div>
                    <Field name="loginPassword" component={renderTextField} type="password" label="Password"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <Button bsStyle="primary" type="submit">Login</Button>
                </div>
            </form>
        )
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'loginForm'
})(LoginForm)
```

From my parent component I am calling it like

```
loginUser = (values) => {

        console.log(values);
}
render() {
   ....
   <LoginForm onSubmit={this.loginUser}/>
   ...
}
```

However, I am getting an empty object in the loginUser function console when I click on Submit button.

I realised that when I change `component={renderTextField}` to `component="input"` in the redux form, I get the value in the loginUser function onSubmit.

I am using `redux-form v6.7.0`

Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redux-form document that was being refered pointed to a version `6.0.0-rc.1` whereas the version being used was `v6.7.0`. Rendering the Text Field like

```
const renderTextField = props => (
  <TextField hintText={props.label}
    floatingLabelText={props.label}
    errorText={props.touched && props.error}
    {...props}
  />
)
```

was giving a warning

```
Warning: Unknown props `input`, `meta` on <input> tag. Remove these props from the element. For details, see 'https://../react-unknown-prop'
    in input (created by TextField)
    in div (created by TextField)
    in TextField (created by renderTextField)
    in renderTextField (created by ConnectedField)
    in ConnectedField (created by Connect(ConnectedField))
    in Connect(ConnectedField) (created by Field)
    in Field (created by LoginForm)
    in div (created by LoginForm)
    in form (created by LoginForm)
    in LoginForm (created by Form(LoginForm))
```

which suggested that the props to TextField needs to be passed differently. The correct way to renderTextField is like

```
const renderTextField = ({input, label, meta: {touched, error}, ...custom}) => (
  <TextField
    style={{width: '80%'}}
    hintText={label}
    floatingLabelText={label}
    errorText={touched && error}
    {...input}
    {...custom}
  />
)
```

The documentation for version `6.7.0` is **[here](http://redux-form.com/6.7.0/examples/material-ui/)**.